# MFC VC++ App Crashes On Vista And XP

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, deployment, mfc

I have developed an application using MFC VC++ and I am want to target all versions of Windows from XP going forward (Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8). I have developed the app on a Windows 7 64 bit machine in VS2012 and it works perfectly but when I attempt to run it on Vista I get the following message:

"A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available"

Here is a screenshot of one of the property pages of the project:

[image: Project Property Pages]

In my targetver.h file I have the following:

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.


#include <winsdkver.h>

#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong? What other information would be helpful?

**EDIT**

I have rebuilt including the `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>` and it still gave the error. The error also appears when running in XP Mode. See below:

[image: XP Crash]

**EDIT 2**

I have managed to build a default MFC Single Document Template and run it on the XP Box. This lead me to dig into the differences between the two applications which lead me to look at the Ouput pane after the application has executed. On the default app this is outputed:

```
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\ShaneH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MFC_Test\Release\MFC_Test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sysfer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18120_none_72d2e82386681b36\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'MFC_Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[6972] MFC_Test.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Which looks like everything is normal and working and then out output from my app:

```
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\ShaneH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MemoryTest\Release\MemoryTest.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sysfer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18120_none_72d2e82386681b36\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcGenral.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\samcli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfc_os.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcXtrnal.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
FTH: (5088): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\ShaneH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MemoryTest\Release\MemoryTest.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\ShaneH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MemoryTest\Release\MemoryTest.exe'
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shunimpl.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SortServer2003Compat.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x01080DD5 in MemoryTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000D0.
First-chance exception at 0x01080DD5 in MemoryTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000D0.
First-chance exception at 0x01080DD5 in MemoryTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000D0.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MemoryTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[5088] MemoryTest.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What are:

- *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***
- And First-chance exception at 0x01080DD5 in MemoryTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000D0?

And possibly more importantly, how do I fix them. The app runs fine on Windows 7, but it doesn't on XP.

**Edit 3**

Reading this [post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32707-Fault-tolerant-heap-on-Windows-7) it seems I need to check my pointers as this might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: As the comment says, you should `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>` *after* the `#define'`s, rather than just comment it out. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Wow I totally missed that part. OK I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @RogerRowland As per my edit I added `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>` after the `#define`'s and the error persists.

Comment: Have you installed the relevant vcredist.exe? I guess [you've read this blog post too](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/visual-studio-2012-update-1-released-real-official-xp-targeting-support/)?

Comment: @RogerRowland I have installed Update 3 from here : http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update, and I followed this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx : meaning that I selected the XP Platform toolset shown in my Configuration screenshot. Is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: Ok, but you also have to install the latest vcredist_x86.exe (or vcredist_x64.exe) on the XP box too - did you do that? [Download link here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Comment: @RogerRowland I downloaded vcredist_x86.exe and installed it on the XP box but the error persisted. On a side note what is vcredist_x86.exe?

Comment: vcredist_x86.exe installs the Visual C Runtime Dlls and MFC/ATL runtime DLLs that VS2012 will have linked to (depending on your project type). For a 32-bit exe you need to install vcredist_x86.exe on the target machine and for a 64-bit exe you need to install vcredist_x64.exe. So these vcredist's need to be distributed and executed by your application installer.

Comment: @RogerRowland Oh OK, I assumed the necessary Dlls were included with Windows by default. Anyway, do you have any other ideas regarding why it doesn't work?

Comment: No further ideas - I guess it's going to be tricky because you can install VS2012 on XP to debug - have to resort to `OutputDebugString` in Release builds and DebugView to see output. It looks like the runtime is ok, so it's either a code problem or a hardware problem (depending on your app) - lots of options...

Comment: There *will* be runtime DLLs installed by default, but they won't be versions compatible with VS2012, hence the need for a refresh.

Comment: Sorry - typo two comments above - you *can't* install VS2012 on XP.

Comment: @RogerRowland I have done some investigation and you are right the problem is with the code. A default MFC app works on the XP box. I have included the output from the output pane in the question: I have a first chance exception and a something about a heap shim. Do you know what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: The access violation you posted indicates that you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer. While you cannot install VS 2012 on Windows XP you can still debug an application using remote debugging. Once you start your application on Windows XP under a debugger you will get very detailed information on where and why you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer. *(Note: You should copy your debug symbols (pdb) into the application directory to get symbolic debugging information.)*

Comment: @IInspectable I have never done any remote debugging, so I am going to have to work out how to do that before I can debug on the XP box. In the mean time can I assume that the `NULL` dereferencing is happening in the set up of the initial main window seeing the error pops up straight away on the XP box?

Comment: Without substantial evidence from a debugging session you should not assume anything. Setting up remote debugging is fairly straight forward. Start the remote debugging host on the target device (XP machine) and change the debugging settings from *Local Debugging* to *Remote Debugging* (setting the required additional fields like target machine, etc.). I usually map my local build output directory as a network drive on the target machine, so that I don't have to copy any files back and forth (thereby usually forgetting one or more vital files).

Comment: @IInspectable, Thank you very much I have managed to resolve my NULL dereferences and now the app work on XP. I appreciate all the help and input!

Comment: @RogerRowland, Thanks so much, I fixed my `NULL` dereference and everything came together.